# Assign same id to rows with same combination of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with many columns, among which the fields **year**, **folder** and **seq_no** serve as an identification method for the record. I'd like to assign the same id to those records that have this combination the same, and (if possible) the total of ids must be sequential, to make good use of the id column values. An example :

```
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  id |year |folder|seq_no|count|
+=====+=====+======+======+=====+
|  1  |1973 |  5   |  11  |  2  | << 1973, 5, 11
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  2  |2010 |  4   |  7   |  2  | << 2010, 4, 7
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  3  |1973 |  11  |  12  |  1  | << 1973, 11, 12
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  1  |1973 |  5   |  11  |  2  | << 1973, 5, 11
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  4  |1500 |  4   |  7   |  1  | << 1500, 4, 7
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  2  |2010 |  4   |  7   |  2  | << 2010, 4, 7
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
```

However, I'd prefer that the id is not assigned by calculation in the php part, but that the table itself on every new entry checks if this entry has the same combination as other ones. If yes, assign same id. If not, assign the next available id.

Also, i would like to count for each row how many records are there with the same id, and this should also be done automatically.

I was thinking of using triggers or functions ... not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to store such IDs and especially COUNT in the table.

Imagine, that in your example you want to insert one more row with

```
+-----+------+------+
|year |folder|seq_no|
+-----+------+------+
|1973 |  5   |  11  |
+-----+------+------+
```

The server would have to find all existing rows with the same combination and update them with the new value of COUNT.

Each `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` becomes really expensive.

This kind of information can be calculated when needed with `DENSE_RANK` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    year
    ,folder
    ,seq_no
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY year, folder, seq_no) AS ID
    ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY year, folder, seq_no) AS cnt
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it at query time:

```
with t (year, folder, seq_no) as (values
    (1973,5,11),
    (2010,4,7),
    (1973,11,12),
    (1973,5,11),
    (1500,4,4),
    (2010,4,7)
)
select
    dense_rank() over (order by year, folder, seq_no) as id,
    year, folder, seq_no,
    count(*) over (partition by year, folder, seq_no) as "count"
from t
;
 id | year | folder | seq_no | count 
----+------+--------+--------+-------
  1 | 1500 |      4 |      4 |     1
  2 | 1973 |      5 |     11 |     2
  2 | 1973 |      5 |     11 |     2
  3 | 1973 |     11 |     12 |     1
  4 | 2010 |      4 |      7 |     2
  4 | 2010 |      4 |      7 |     2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build a unique index base on multiple column like so :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX year_folder_seqNo ON my_table (year, folder, seq_no);
```

This will prevent multiple insert with same values (thus you will only have 1 row for each combination)