# SQL Server get unique Id with same combination of numbers

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a view, something similar to this post:

[Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406989/assign-same-id-to-rows-with-same-combination-of-data)

but I need to create same id always for the same combination of items, for example if I have 2 columns with values 34, 67, this combination will give me always the same id, by the way, the id must be unique, if I have another combination like 3, 467, should be another id.

The view will have 3 columns

```
Id, Value1, Value2
```

`Id` will be generated according to `Value1` and `Value2`:

```
Id   Value1   Value2
---------------------
??   34        67
??    3       467
```

The same combination of `Value1` and `Value2` will always return the same `Id`, I need to find a way of generating these ids based on these columns

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to find a function or something to return same result for same combination but I couldn't find anything yet

Comment: @carlosm could you please post some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: Why don't you use `DENSE_RANK() over(order by Value1, Value2) as id` as suggested in link you've posted?

Comment: What your talking about is a unique bijective mapping of natural numbers between 2D and 1D. This is commonly known as a pairing function. If you're not afraid of a little bit of math, the Wikipedia article has a great example of the cantor pairing function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: DENSE_RANK will not give me the same id result, is there any sql function for pairing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a procedure to get ID for specific value pair. If exists, you getit. If not, it is generated and stored.

Table to store all value pairs with unique ID

```
create table  idval1val2 (id int identity, value1 int not null, value2 int not null)
go
```

Procedure to obtain ID for any value pair

```
create procedure getID(@value1 int, @value2 int, @id int OUT) as

if exists(select id from idval1val2 where value1=@value1 and value2=@value2)
begin
    select @id=id from idval1val2 where value1=@value1 and value2=@value2
end
 else 
begin
   insert into idval1val2(value1,value2) values(@value1,@value2)
   set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end
 go
```

If values can be in any order, it need a smal change.

Comment: The idea was not to create a table because if I need to create a table, I'll use directly the IDENTITY column

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash function

```
  select  HashBytes ( 'MD5', cast(@value1 as char(20)) ) 
        + HashBytes ( 'MD5', cast(@value2 as char(20)) )
```

This will bring you a concatenated values of each hashed value (as var binary). This will be unique and always the same, in any system without storage.

Example:

```
 select HashBytes ( 'MD5', '134' ) , HashBytes ( 'MD5', '2' ) 
      , HashBytes ( 'MD5', '134' ) + HashBytes ( 'MD5', '2' )
```

> 0x02522A2B2726FB0A03BB19F2D8D9524D    0xC81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C  0x02522A2B2726FB0A03BB19F2D8D9524DC81E728D9D4C2F636F067F89CC14862C

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create your own hash function. Something like this will do:

```
select @id= cast(@value1 as varchar(20)) +'.'+cast(@value2 as varchar(20))
```

this is always unique and brings the same ID, in this case, varchar(41).

You can do a DECIMAL (4,4) not sure what your domain is

```
select @id= @value1 + @value2/10000.0
```

etc